TINA AC Transfer Characteristic and Transient sims give different results
I have the following active filter circuit:

I found this design in a book and it should have the following parameters:

center freq: 1 kHz
Q = 40
gain: 16 dB @ 1 kHz (on OUT1)

As the AC transfer charasteristic sim shows, the circuit is working as it should:

But when it comes to the transient sim, I get different results. I use a 1 kHz sine wave with 10 mV amplitude as an input and I expect a 1 kHz sine wave with an amplitude of around >60 mV on the OUT1 (16 dB = 6.3) but the gain isn't bigger as 5 as you can see on the picture below:

I use ideal elements, ideal opamp and I just can't figure it out why does the 2 simulations give different results. I hope you can help me!

Did you wait a sufficient time (?) ... I simulated it and the results are ok.

With a Q of 40, you should wait at least 40 cycles (40 msec) to give time for the filter to settle out.

Since the Q of the BPF seems quite large, I would increase the accuracy for the transient analysis.
Analysis > Options > Transient > Integrations order set from default 2 to 6.


Thanks for your help!
